# SQL Server 2008: SQLXML Query function .query('//mypath/text()') doesn't XML decode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xpath, sqlxml

In Microsoft SQL Server 2008, when executing `.query('{xpath}/text()')` on an XML stream column value, if the value of the XPath selected node contains "`&amp;`", the return value is "`&amp`" instead of "`&`".

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Or rather, how do I get the unencoded text, i.e. equivalent of .innerText (per W3C XML DOM), with SQLXML XPath if text() in the XPath query isn't supposed to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No bug, SQL XML decodes XML escape sequences correctly:

```
declare @x xml;
set @x = '<node>&amp;some</node>';
select @x.value(N'(node)[1]', N'varchar(max)');
```

What most likely is your problem  is a misunderstanding on your part of the XML [query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx) method: it returns an **XML** fragment, and as such all content will be... escaped, since it's XML:

```
declare @x xml;
set @x = '<node>&amp;some</node>';
select @x.query(N'/node/text()');
```

Comment: So then how do you get the decoded *text*, i.e. the .InnerText as equivalent in XML DOM? Or is that possible in SQLXML?

Comment: My first code snippet, using value('(node)[1]') shows just that, it returns the XML element node value (ie. the `text()`).

Comment: How in XPath? My desired node is not @ root.

Comment: .. I figured it out .. 
CAST({column} as XML).query('{xpath query}').value(N'({node})[1]', N'varchar(max)')

Comment: or rather .value(N'({xpath query})[1]', N'varchar(max)')